# Observe the date in android

Tags: android, date, contentobserver

Is it possible to observe the date (e.g. like a ContentObserver) so that every time the date changes (either because the time elapsed or the user changed it manually), some code get's executed?

The reason why I need this is the following: I've got a list which is backed by a cursor. The cursor is the result of a SQLite statement containing a predicate `date >= strftime('%Y-%m-%d','now')`. So if the date changes, some list items have to be removed from the list (which will obviously happen after calling `requery()` on the cursor).

Comment: The date changes constantly... There is no situation in which the time now is equal to now + any increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just re-query whenever your app is resumed? That would ensure that it's always queried against the current date, because they can't change the date without pausing your app. The other thing to note is that this seems like a real edge case. How often to users change the date (not just the time of day, as you are only comparing m, d, y) manually?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) class.

Once the app starts, 
1) calculate the time required to sleep until the next day.
2) Start a timer to "wake" at that time,
3) Once that timer finishes, start another timer to wake 24 hours later
4) Execute the code you want to run.
5) Repeat step 3.

Comment: I thought about a similar approach as well (but using Androids Handler-Class). The problem is: What happens if the user changes the date? Another problem is, when the time is synchronized with a time-server, the thread could wake up too early (too late would be better than too early for my situation).

Comment: There are a couple more strategies that you could use, though it all depends on how close to midnight you need this to be.  In the question, could you expand your requirements?  Is it a strict, the date has been changed... what is it you are trying to accomplish?  Maybe listening to the date changed isn't the right thing to watch...